# Perl SQLite driver stopped working after I installed MySQL driver

Tags: mysql, perl, sqlite

I have always successfully used Perl with SQLite, using `DBI` and `DBD::SQLite`.

Recently I installed a MySQL client and server on my Ubuntu system, as well as `DBD::mysql`. MySQL works fine, but after installing the Perl module I ran a different project on SQLite and I got the message that there was no `DBD::SQLite`.

I reinstalled `DBD::SQLite` using CPAN and now the databases that I created seem no longer to be valid files. If I create a very simple database like this

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=test.db","","") or die $DBI::errstr;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER, name char(100), PRIMARY KEY (id))");

$sth->execute(); 
$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect();
```

and then try to open this file using *SQLiteStudio* I get the message

```
Error while opening test.db: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

In the Linux console the following message appears

```
file is encrypted or is not a database
    while executing
"sqlite2 $name $_path"
    (object "::sqlite20" method "::Sqlite2::createDbObject" body line 2)
invoked from within
    "createDbObject ::database$dbNum"
```

So apparently installing `DBD::mysql` screwed with `DBD:SQLite`.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this happened and how to fix it?

Comment: Your connection string is very laconic. The documentation shows `my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$dbfile","","");`

Comment: @choroba: Agreed. In my experience you can get away with `undef` for the user and pass (so you really only need to provide the DSN) but a bare file name is a little extreme, and is consistent with the lax spelling and formatting of the question itself before my edit.

Comment: Sorry, actually that was bad copy and paste, the string is as you posted - that is because I used a variable and I just "sloppily" replaced it by the DB name. I am trying to edit it but a moderator has edited it and now it complains that the links he put are not properly formatted.

Comment: Ok I removed the links and edited it, my code is correct and unfortunately the bug has to do with something else. Sorry mod for removing the links you added.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 1.00 in 2004, DBD::SQLite comes with SQLite 3 and thus creates and manipulates SQLite 3 databases. You're using tools that create and manipulate SQLite 2 databases. They are not compatible.

> The format used by SQLite database files has been completely revised. The old version 2.1 format and the new 3.0 format are incompatible with one another. Version 2.8 of SQLite will not read a version 3.0 database files and version 3.0 of SQLite will not read a version 2.8 database file.

Quoted from SQLite [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/version3.html) written when SQLite 3 came out.

Downgrade DBD::SQLite to a version earlier than 1.00 or use `sqlite3` instead of `sqlite2`.

Comment: I am using up-to-date software, I've always used SQLite 3 and supposedly sqlite-studio is also prepared for sqlite3. I will test this later today but unfortunately I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Everything worked fine until I decided to install DBD::mysql.

Comment: I don't know what happened to your original DBD::SQLite, and it's really not important. Nothing's stopping you from installing an old version of DBD::SQLite.

Comment: Re "I am using up-to-date software", I'd rather believe the text you copied from screen that says you used `sqlite2`.